# Add One DataView to Another in C#

Tags: c#, asp.net, ado.net, dataview

I need to add two DataViews together to have one Dataview that can then be bound to a Repeater.

I am plugging into someone else's API so I can't change the way the data is retreived at the SQL Level.

So essentially I want to do this:

```
DataView dView1 = getActiveModules();
DataView dView2 = getInactiveModules();

ModuleView = dView1 + dView2;

rptModules.DataSource = ModuleView.Tables[0];
rptModules.DataBind();
```

The two schemas for the views are identical just retrieving active and inactive modules.

Any ideas?

Thanks.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

you can merge your dataview like...

```
System.Data.DataView dv = new System.Data.DataView();
System.Data.DataView dv1 = new System.Data.DataView();
dv.Table.Merge(dv1.Table);
```

Answer (score 3):

You can easily combine/merge the two views (data tables) into one data table.

#### Example Syntax

```
    Dim a As DataView
    Dim b As DataView

    a.Table.Merge(b.Table)

    Dim c As New DataView
    c.Table.Merge(a.Table) 'might generate error because c.Table is null
```

From http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.datatable.merge.aspx

> **DataTable.Merge Method**  Merge the specified DataTable with the current
> DataTable.
>
> The Merge method is used to merge two
> DataTable objects that have largely
> similar schemas. A merge is typically
> used on a client application to
> incorporate the latest changes from a
> data source into an existing
> DataTable. This allows the client
> application to have a refreshed
> DataTable with the latest data from
> the data source.
>
> The merge operation takes into account
> only the original table, and the table
> to be merged. Child tables are not
> affected or included. If a table has
> one or more child tables, defined as
> part of a relationship, each child
> table must be merged individually.